# Get full activity log (not commit log) for a local git repo

Tags: git, github

I am working on a personal project [Gitty](http://github.com/sanskar-modi/gitty), Unofficial client for git. It uses git command line output to show necessary data.
I want to plot graph like `gitk` for git repo using (Gitgraphjs)[http://gitgraphjs.com] and for this i want output something like this showing all activities

```
Initial commit - master
Some more commit - master
created new branch develop             #branch created
Some more commits in master - master
added bla bla - develop
merged master and develop             #branch merged
some commit - master
```

I tried using `git log --all --oneline` and `git reflog` but it didn't gave necessary data like when particular branch created. I can parse that `git log --graph --oneline` output but i don't think that's the right way of doing it.

I want to know what command should i use or is there any others way for plotting graph.

Comment: Git does not record branch creation.  Even if it did record this, it would not be generally useful.  Just because there's a `develop` *now* does not mean there will be a `develop` tomorrow, or if there is, it may be unrelated to today's.  What *is* useful is the structure of the commit graph, but you (and Git) must derive that dynamically by reading the parent IDs from each commit and comparing those IDs to the IDs of every other commit.  If commit 1234567 has commits 3333333 and 5555555 as its parents, then commit 1234567 is a merge that joins up whatever branches are going at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`git-reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) will provide you the git activity history you need as it provides activity history beyond commits. I sometimes use it to view pushes and correlate the pushes with commits.

```
git show reflog
```

From the ref log you can see activities such as branch, checkout, clone, commit, commit(merge), merge, pull, push, reset, and revert.

It appears the best way to determine when a branch was created is finding the first checkout in the log where the destination branch is seen for the first time.

You won't see pushes in the reflog for your local branch. For that you would use git reflog on your remote branch where you will see pushes to the origin.

```
git reflog show origin/mybranch
```

Note: `git reflog show` is an alias for `git log -g --abbrev-commit --pretty=oneline` and any of the `git log` command line options can be passed to `git reflog show` also, `show` is optional as it is the default for `git reflog`